# Pulse Counter on Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I need a function which returns the number of pulses during a specified time, on arduino.This is the partial code I'm using, but the function isn't retuning anything ( isn't returning even 0 )

...

```
long Itime = 0;
int Dtime = 25;
```

...

```
int Counter() {
    unsigned long Ftime = millis();
    int c = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while ( Ftime - Itime < Dtime ) {
        if ( digitalRead(PSPin) == HIGH ) {
            i=i+1;
            while ( digitalRead(PSPin) == HIGH) { // delays the function until
                c=c+1;                        // the next cycle
                c=c-1;
            }   
        }
    }
    Itime = Ftime;
    return i;
    }
```

I really don't understand why the function isn't returning 'i'.I'd be happy if someone could help.Thanks

edit:
The signal on PSPin is a 150hz square signal, which means that the period is approximately 6ms, and since my time is 25ms it should return at least 3 pulses.. 
I called this function for testing purposes only, since I also think my program gets stuck on the Counter() function, but I can't figure out why.

```
void loop() {
     if ( Counter() == 0 )
     digitalWrite(TestPinA, HIGH);
     if ( Counter() > 0 )
     digitalWrite(TestPinB, HIGH);
     }
```

But both pins never return HIGH.
I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I suppose "isn't returning anything" means the program gets stuck in the `Counter` function. It doesn't return because either `Ftime - Itime < Dtime` is never true in the first while, or more likely because `digitalRead(PSPin)` always returns `HIGH`.

Comment: How can it not return *anything*? You must be calling it somehow, like `count = Counter()`, so what's the value of `count` (or whatever variable you're using) after the call? Perhaps you should show the code where you call the function.

Comment: I've just edited my post.I also think that that's the problem, it's getting stucked on the function, but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are stuck in the

```
while ( Ftime - Itime < Dtime )
```

as the code never actually update either of Ftime or Dtime, while in the WHILE loop. Try the following:

```
int PSPin = 13;
int DurationTime = 25; // best to have same type as compare or cast it later, below.

int Counter() {
    int i = 0;
    unsigned long StartTime = millis();
    unsigned long PrvTime = StartTime ;
    while ( PrvTime - StartTime < (unsigned long) DurationTime ) {
        if ( digitalRead(PSPin) == HIGH ) {
            i=i+1;
            while ( digitalRead(PSPin) == HIGH); // BLOCK the function until cycles
        }
        PrvTime = millis();
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!I'm new at this, so I'm getting stuck with simple mistakes.I really appreciate you help!

Answer (score 0):

Use Interrupts to make the work easy.

```
volatile int IRQcount;
int pin = 2;
int pin_irq = 0; //IRQ that matches to pin 2

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
attachInterrupt(pin_irq, IRQcounter, RISING);
delay(25);
detachInterrupt(pin);
Serial.print(F("Counted = ");
Serial.println(IRQcount);
}

void IRQcounter() {
  IRQcount++;
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

And if you wanted to use a pin other than INT0/1. You can use [PinChangeInt Libray](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/PinChangeIntExample) to use any pin.

Comment: Thanks.This is a great way to do what I want.I'm gonna try it..but I still would like to now why my function is wrong..